# Web app for scheduling dates (like when2meet but excluding time-of-day)

Tags: web-apps, collaboration, scheduling

I’m trying to schedule multi-day events with others. And I’d like to include multiple months in the polling range. Example: “is there a stretch of 3-5 days this summer that works for everyone?”

Any recommendations for a web app that supports this?

I like when2meet and Doodle for scheduling something where time-of-day is a factor, but it gets in the way for this sort of multi-day scheduling. And they don’t make it easy to look at many weeks at once.

*Update*: to clarify what I'm looking for, I've [built my own](https://github.com/entrity/date-collaboration), and I'm sharing a screenshot. But still, I'd like a 3rd-party app with 3rd-party support (and, ideally, a cleverer interface).

[image]

I'd like voters to not have to pick items from a pre-defined list but instead to be able to mark all dates that are particularly good or bad for them. In the **left column**, I've cast some 'yes' votes (green) and 'no' votes (red). In the **two columns on the right**, you can see that the 'no' votes and 'yes' votes are aggregated from all the voters so that we can find a stretch of however-may-days that works best for the most people.

Answer (score 2):

With [PollUnit](https://pollunit.com) you can create different types of polls. When you create a PollUnit with the type "Voting", you can choose what to vote on. This includes among other things:

- Date
- Date with time
- Date range
- Date range with time

Disclosure: I work for PollUnit.

Comment: Thanks. I've just played around with it, and it looks really pretty. I'm really trying to let the voters define their own date ranges by marking all dates that are either good or bad for them. (See the new screenshot and updated description in the question above.) I don't see how to do that. Is there a way in PollUnit?

Comment: This is an interesting idea to find a suitable date range. Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment. Just one more thought: I am not sure if it is beneficial to consider what the participants' favorite days are. You could ask only for the days when there is no time. In the summary you would then see which days have the highest resistance. However, you would then have to determine the appropriate range yourself.